# Peut-on utiliser l'adjectif « estival » pour un climat tropical?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage

J'ai lu cette phrase-la dans un article:

> Des campeurs ont eu une grosse frayeur dans la nuit de samedi à dimanche en Australie, en pleine période de vacances scolaires **estivales**.

Source, [Le Figaro](http://www.lefigaro.fr/sciences/2015/09/28/01008-20150928ARTFIG00369-australie-un-trou-geant-avale-un-terrain-de-camping.php)

Or, dans l'hémisphère sud, il y a grosso modo six mois de décalage dans les saisons, ce qui rendrait le terme « printanier » plus approprié.

Mais, en plus, la zone est tropicale, avec deux saisons: sèche et humide.

Donc, est-il vraiment correct d'utiliser le terme « estivale » dans un tel contexte? Sinon, quel adjectif faudrait-il utiliser?

Comment: Les campeurs en question étaient-ils australiens? S'ils venaient d'Europe ou d'Amérique du nord "vacances estivales" désignerait simplement les vacances d'été.

Comment: A priori c'était les vacances scolaires du Queensland (19 Sept. - 5 Oct.). Donc je dirais que les vacanciers (la plupart en tout cas) étaient des Australiens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cet [article](http://www.australia.com/en/planning/australian-school-holidays.html) semble confirmer que c'est en effet le début des vacances de printemps :

> Western Australia: 26 September to 11 October
>   Spring school holiday ideas

La citation du Figaro fait référence à [cet article](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2015-09-28/inskip-point-sinkhole-gets-own-facebook-likes-and-youtube-video/6809428), et on découvre que la phrase d'origine est en fait :

> [...] in the middle of the **busy school holiday period**.

Il semble donc que c'est erreur du journaliste, qui a traduit/interprété à sa façon.